# Magento 2 Knockout Component after initialize hook or method

Tags: magento2, component, knockout

In the knockout component I have

```
initialize: function () {

    this._super();

    var self = this;

    ....some code....
}
```

I want to move the **....some code....** part into **afterInitilize()** method, but I can't find such a thing. Is there some hook, that runs right after initialize is done ? How can I accomplish that, if not ?